# Algorithm for partitioning set of sets into approximately equal-sized chunks?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Consider a set A of n finite sets, *whose members are not necessarily disjoint*. Let P={P[1], P[2], ..., P[m]} be a partition of A, and for each i in 1..m, let U[i] be the union of all of the elements of P[i]. So U={U[1], U[2], ..., U[m]}. I would like an algorithm to a find a P such that the corresponding U is a partition, and such that the difference in cardinality (i.e. size) between the smallest and largest elements of U is minimised.

Characteristics of the data:

- m is small (2 to 5) and n<10000
- Typically, there is a large proportion of 1-element sets in A
- Intersections between pairs of sets in A are typically small or empty

Comment: Is it an university assignment?

Comment: "I would like an algorithm to a find a P such that the corresponding U is a partition" A partition of what? As far as I can tell, the members of U[i] are the members of the members of P[i] and A... Could you give a concrete example of what you're talking about?

Comment: @jswolf A partition of the union of all the elements of U. That union is actually the same as the union of all the elements of A. To put it more simply, I could have said "the elements of U are pairwise disjoint". To give a concrete example, consider a box of necklaces, where each necklace has one or more beads on it, and some of the necklaces may be tied to each other at one or more points. I want to sort the necklaces into piles, without separating or cutting them, so that the piles contain equal numbers of beads, or as near as possible to equal numbers of beads. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My necklace analogy in the question comments suggests this solution:

1. Build an undirected graph G whose vertices are the elements of A, and where there is an edge from A[i] to A[j] iff A[i] intersects A[j].
2. Find the connected components C of G. This can be done with a simple breadth-first or depth-first algorithm.
3. For each C[i], take the vertices of C[i] and union them together, yielding D[i]. You now have reduced the problem to a special case, because the set D is a partition of the union of the elements of A.
4. Use a bin-packing algorithm to try and fit the elements of D into precisely m bins, each of size ceil(t/m) where t is the size of the union of all the elements of D. If that fails, increase the sizes of the bins repeatedly until either it succeeds or it's clear that it's never going to succeed. Bin-packing algorithms are typically heuristic, so a perfect solution might not be found. Also, this is more than a simple bin-packing problem, so even a perfect bin-packing algorithm might not find the optimal solution.

I'd be interested to know if there is a more efficient solution. In particular, I have a hunch that the repeated use of the bin-packing algorithm in step 4 is not sensible.

Comment: I don't know if it would be optimal, but I wonder if you couldn't just go with the greedy algorithm of ordering the elements of D by size and, from the largest, putting each element into the bin with the smallest count...

Comment: 1-element sets in A make bin packing easier because they fill in empty spaces. Are you sure that your bin-packing instances are actually hard?

Comment: The one-element sets of A are only useful if they are in their own connected components in the graph described above.  The key numbers are the sizes of the D(i)s.  Lots of singletons aren't really helpful if, say, one of your sets in A is the entire universe of the problem space.

Comment: On the other hand, the one-element sets of A do make the task of generating the intersection graph faster...

Comment: The final part of the problem, which is essentially a bin-packing problem, is NP-complete, right?  So for a usable algorithm, we need to get a handle on the expected number if D(i)s and the distribution of their sizes.

Comment: Okay, given k positive integers, n(1), ... n(k), if we want to find whether there exists a subset that adds up to half the total, then this problem is NP-complete.  But give such a sequence, I can find a problem of your original form with n(1)+...+n(k) sets in A and at most k of them have more than one element, and the pairwise intersections of the sets all have sizes zero or one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the intersection graph of A, which has nodes elements of A and edges when the two nodes have a non-empty intersection.  Each connected component of this graph has to be contained in a single P(i) for some i.

let C(1),...,C(k) be the connected components of the graph.  Let

```
size(j)=|union(a in C(j))|
```

Now you can rewrite the problem in terms of the size(i) values, with i=1...k. Namely, given positive integer values s(1),..,s(k).  For a subset P of [1,..k] we define s(P)=sum(j in P) s(j).

We want to find a partition P'=(P'(1),...,P'(m)) of [1,..,k] with the condition that it minimizes the value:

```
max s(P'(j)) - min s(P'(j))
```

Therefore, we really need to know not the likely sizes of the elements of A, but the likely sizes of the connected components of the graph to come up with a "best" algorithm.

Comment: I see this is the same answer as given by Robin, who wrote it more eloquently.